# Form Hangs when Closing, Minimizing, or Maximizing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# Windows Forms app that runs perfectly fine on most machines. But some machines when closing child forms (not an MDI app) the entire app hangs for a few seconds until the window is closed. This only occurs when clicking the 'X' button in the upper right corner. If I have a button on the form that just calls `this.Close();` the window closes fine. I have about 20 machines this works fine on, but I have seen 2 so far that this issue is occuring on (one is Windows 7 the other is XP). If I run the code from Visual Studio on those machines the windows do close fine. It only happens when running from the EXE. When closing the main form of the app there is no hanging. Just the child forms. I am just using

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Show();
```

to open the window. I have tried this on blank test forms in the same app that have no code and the same thing happens. With other Windows Forms apps on the same machines this issue does not occur. There is something specific about this app that is causing this but I cannot narrow it down. I know this is a difficult question to answer without seeing the entire code base, but has anyone else come across a similar issue to this in the past? Thank you.

EDIT: Some Additional Notes

The minimize, maximize, and restore buttons cause the same hang when any of them are clicked on.

Interestingly, if you click on the window icon in the upper left corner and select Close, Minimize, or Maximize those all work fine with no delay or hanging.

Comment: Calling `Show` only sets `Visible` to `true`. Both clicking on the `X` button and calling `Close` raises the `Closing` event -- no difference here. Have you tried to hack together a simple application with a main form, few child forms, and the Close button on the main form?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on your form closing event put

```
Application.Exit(); //use to stop application processes
```

Go on your task manager and and go to processes tab and check if your application causes high amount of CPU usage. Maybe there are still instance of your application that still running.

Regards